# Changes to record in table while form is open - record locking

Tags: ms-access-2007, record-locking

I have a design for a multi-user database:
1. Form A is used to update Table A and Table B (simultaneously On Click)
2. Form B is used to review Table B, approve records, then delete them from Table B

The problem is if Form B is opened on a record (with Primary Key CASENUMBER) and the record for that CASENUMBER is edited in Form A.

How do I put a lock on a specific record so that if it is being viewed in a form it cannot be viewed/edited in another?

Comment: Add a field called `[In_Use]` that is a checkbox.  When a record is pulled, set the `In_Use` to `TRUE`, when the form is closed, set all to `FALSE`.  Then when an edit needs to be made, check first for `In_Use = TRUE`

Comment: Would this work if the forms are being pulled from separate tables? I'd add the IN_USE field to both tables and do a join, but would that be enough for Access to recognize that CASENUMBER 10000 is open in Form A (from Table A) so don't allow it to be open in Form B (from Table B)?

Comment: I'd make a field in each table accourdingly, `In_Use_A` and `B`, that way if the join flags either table then it can report back which table has a record (or part of a record) in use.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. What would the syntax look like to set the In_Use field to 'True' and 'False' based on if the record is pulled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on your syntax question:

First you would need to modify your SQL statement to include the `IN_USE_A` and `IN_USE_B`.  Once a record is pulled but before it is put into the form, you would set a recordset based on that record and then make the field for each table true.

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim myR As Recordset

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE criteria_here"

Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
'myR is now that record and can be manipulated/data pulled from

myR.Edit
myR![IN_USE_A] = TRUE
myR.Update

'perform tasks and such

'then just before closing

myR.Edit
myR![IN_USE_A] = FALSE
myR.Update

Set myR = Nothing
```

Comment: After making the appropriate changes I get an error on the Set myR line "...cannot find the input table or query 'False'." Does the value in IN_USE need to be set to False before it can be made true?Thanks for your help TKEyi60

Comment: That means it cannot find the table you're querying.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287696 see here.  Make sure everything is properly typed in regards to naming.